# $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is only $n$-time(s) differentiable at $0$ or on an infinite discrete set of $\mathbb{R}$ but is smooth elsewhere?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

(1) What are some functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is only $n$-time(s) differentiable at $0$ but is smooth elsewhere? ($n$ is a positive integer.)

(2) What are some functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that are only only n-time(s) differentiable on an infinite discrete set of $\mathbb{R}$ but is smooth elsewhere? ($n$ is a positive integer.)

For (1) my example is $f(x)=|x|^\frac{2n+1}{2}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

For (2) my example is $f(x)=|\sin{x}|^\frac{2n+1}{2}$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Are there more different-looking examples?

(If switching "infinite discrete set" to "infinite proper subset", will the question of this post become more interesting/fun? Or is it better to ask that case in a separate post?)

Comment: Consider the $f_n(x)=x^n\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ and the $g_n(x)=f_n(\sin{x})$.

Comment: @Mindlack Please elaborate and verify your examples. (1) How are your functions defined at 0? (2) If you define $f_2(0)=0$, it seems that $f_2$ is not finitely differentiable at $0$ when checking with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+D%5BD%5BD%5BD%5BD%5BD%5BD%5BPiecewise%5B%7B%7Bx%5E2*sin%281%2Fx%29%2Cx%21%3D0%7D%2C%7B0%2Cx%3D0%7D%7D%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D).

Comment: 1) for $n \geq 1$, $f_n(0)=0$ is the only way to define $f_n$ at $0$ so that the function is continuous. 2) what exactly is finitely differentiable? 2’) you can check by hand that $f’_2$ exists everywhere but is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Mindlack Sorry, by "finitely differentiable" I mean "$n$-times differentiable with $n$ being a positive integer. I have edited and corrected it.

Comment: @Mindlack Hello! :-) If switching "infinite discrete set" to "infinite proper subset", will the question of this post become more interesting/fun? Or is it better to ask that case in a separate post?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f_0$ defined by 
$$
f_0(x) = |x|
$$
is $0$-times differentiable at $0$, but smooth elsewhere, and continuous everywhere.

Define, for integer $n > 0$, 
$$
f_n(x) = \int_0^x f_{n-1}(t)~ dt
$$
Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f_n$ (for $n > 0$) is differentiable everywhere, and its derivative is $f_{n-1}$, from which we see that $f_n$ is in fact smooth away from $0$, but exactly $n$-times differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Hello! :-) If switching "infinite discrete set" to "infinite proper subset", will the question of this post become more interesting/fun? Or is it better to ask that case in a separate post?

Comment: Oh...I forgot all about item 2 in the question, so I guess my answer is a half-answer. But it can easily be turned into a full answer, for  a countable discrete set $x_i$, by replacing $f_0$ with something like $f_0(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} |x - x_i|$, which has a "bad point" at each of the special points $x_i$. If your "inner function" ("abs" in my original example) has one bad point, but is everywhere zero outside some small interval around that bad point ($\exp(x^{-2})$ is often used in building these), then you can make something like that approach work, I believe.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a "soft min" of the absolute values of $x - x_i$. Anyhow, I leave the details to someone else who doesn't have to leave for work shortly.

Comment: To answer what you asked: definitely ask in a separate question (there's no cost to asking more questions!). It's kinda rude to change a question after folks have already provided answers (although in this case it might be OK, as mine's only a half-answer, and no one else has answered yet. But someone might be typing at this very moment...)